# Load balancer 404 : Weblogic 9,2

Tags: load, load-balancing, weblogic9.x

Apologies if my question is a bit silly. I am new to weblogic and the concepts of load balancer and weblogic. I am witnessing a lot of 404 errors in the production evironment. Can anyone help me from where shall i start my invetsigation.

Regards

Comment: Seems too broad. Try adding examples, links and relevant configuration details.

Comment: I have a cluster environment with 2 physical UNIX boxes. Each physical box has a load balancer. Each UNIX box has 4 application servers. Recently in production evironment I am witnessing a lot of 404 errors in LB access logs. When I am checking the log files of individual application servers, I cant see any error getting updated. As mentioned previuosly I am very new to cluster environment. Really dont know from where shall i start. Any pointers would be good

Comment: another thing which I have recently witnessed that out of the two laod balancers only one is facing lot of 404 issues